# Can i use regex in the Record Separator in awk in linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have the test file like this

```
fdsf fdsf fdsfds fdsf
fdsfdsfsdf fdsfsf
fsdfsdf var12=1343243432

fdsf fdsf fdsfds fdsf
fdsfsdfdsfsdf
fsdfsdf var12=13432434432

fdsf fdsf fdsfds fdsf
fsdfsdf fdsfsf var12=13443432432
```

Now i want to use   `var12=\d+` as the record separator. Is this possible in awk

Comment: Yes (see the other answers) but setting RS to the null string to separate records by blank lines would be just about as useful given your posted input and it'd work in any awk.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, however you should use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`:

```
awk '1' RS="var12=[0-9]+" file
```

IIRC, only `GNU awk` can use multi-character record separators.

Results:

```
fdsf fdsf fdsfds fdsf
fdsfdsfsdf fdsfsf
fsdfsdf 


fdsf fdsf fdsfds fdsf
fdsfsdfdsfsdf
fsdfsdf 


fdsf fdsf fdsfds fdsf
fsdfsdf fdsfsf
```

Please post your desired output if you need further assistance.

Comment: Thanks steve , you are my hero. How did u become so great in sed awk

Comment: I use with these tools regularly. And I learn on SO. Or at least, I think I learn. +1's all round.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming [GNU awk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) (a.k.a. `gawk`) on Linux, yes.

> `RS`
>
> This is awk's input record separator. Its default value is a string containing a single newline character, which means that an input record consists of a single line of text. It can also be the null string, in which case records are separated by runs of blank lines. **If it is a regexp, records are separated by matches of the regexp in the input text.**

**Source:** [7.5.1 Built-in Variables That Control `awk`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/User_002dmodified.html#User_002dmodified), [The GNU Awk User's Guide](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/).

As [@steve says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14742491/78845), `\d` is not in the list of [Regular Expression Operators](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Operators.html#Regexp-Operators) or [`gawk`-Specific Regexp Operators](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/GNU-Regexp-Operators.html#GNU-Regexp-Operators), so you need to use a [bracket expression](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Bracket-Expressions.html#Bracket-Expressions) such as `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]` in place of your `\d`.

However, it's not clear from your question as to what your intention here is. I've answered your question but I doubt I've solved your underlying problem. See also [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147331)